# Cannot login with service account on Google Earth Engine npm

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I've been trying to login into my service account on the Google Earth Engine npm library. For some reason, it keeps telling me that I'm not logged in, even though I am supplying the JSON key file of my service account that has owner rights over my project.

```js
import ee from "@google/earthengine";
import privateKey from "./privateKey.js";


const runAnalysis = function () {
    ee.initialize(null, null, function () {
        // ... run analysis ...
    }, function (e) {
        console.error('Initialization error: ' + e);
    });
};

ee.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey(privateKey, runAnalysis, function (e) {
    console.error('Authentication error: ' + e);
});

const image = new ee.Image('srtm90_v4');
image.getMap({ min: 0, max: 1000 }, function (map) {
    console.log(map);
});
```

My `privateKey.js` looks like:

```js
export default {
  "type": "secret",
  "project_id": "secret",
  "private_key_information": "secret",
  "private_key": "secret",
  "client_email": "secret",
  "client_id": "secret",
  "auth_uri": "secret",
  "token_uri": "secret",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "secret",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "secret"
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Does anyone know how I could debug this issue?

Comment: Check that your import is correct. If my reading of the standard is correct and I am not in a place to test, you are asking to import the object `privateKey` from file `privateKey.js` but the contents of `privateKey,js` isn't exporting an object named that. The closest is `private_key` object. Just `console.log` your parameters just before the call, make sure they are what you are expecting.

Comment: My import is correct, if I log privateKey it is showing the json. An `export default` means that you can name the corresponding import however you like.

Comment: Understood, my JS is very rusty. Could this be a factor? https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/service_account#use-a-default-service-account

Comment: I think that could be a factor yes, I'll try that tomorrow. Thank you :)

Comment: I am still not able to get the authentication working on the npm module. It's working fine  in a python script I wrote. Thank you very much for the suggestion; it helped me create a working service account authentication in python.